# Woocommerce Storefront WordPress Ignore Media Gallery Images and use External 3rd Party Host

Tags: functions, custom-field, images, import, hosting

OK, firstly we have done this before using Magento and it worked well, but with WordPress? Well, here is the problem and the plan...

## The Problem

For a few reasons we wish to use a 3rd Party host for all our e-commerce images in the Storefront Theme of Woocommerce. As we are using an import tool to populate, update and manage 30,000+ products, the whole import process runs far too slowly because of the way WordPress handles images by default.

It wants to import source images and store them in the media gallery locally, which makes no sense when we already have them safely hosted elsewhere, at every stage of the import.

## WordPress

We know that when images are uploaded to WP they are stored in the media gallery, the Storefront theme then gets a choice of several versions, optimised and resized, thanks to WordPress. So a large image uploaded, has say a 500 x 500, 300 x 300 and so forth created too.

## Our idea

1 - When we run our import we would like to include the original source URL of the images (on the 3rd party host) in a Custom Field we create. That way each product has this as a reference point. *This bit is easy and can prepare for this using the WP All Import plugin we already use.*

2 - We would prefer a functions.php edit at this next stage, rather than find each template and try to hack where the images are pulled from:

So, in the product page template - rather than to use the WP Gallery, we would like to use the image location from the custom field we have populated above.

A max size would need to be allocated to resize the image to say a max width of 500px, to keep it within the constraints of the product page theme.

3 - The same for all other parts of the site, say search results / section templates are all pulling in the very same image referenced in the custom field.

Just different sizes allocated accordingly depending on the image locations of course.

Sounds simple? Just not really sure how to call the custom field for the relevant product and tell the Storefront templates to use that instead of the WP Gallery.

Would love to hear if anyone has done this before and how they achieved this.

Many thanks in advance!